# How to repeat a particular statement after getting exception in java?

Tags: java

As we know that when an exception occurs we catch it with "try and catch" and the program runs forward but I want the program to run from the point where exception originally occurred.  Below is an example of a mini calculator that I made.  When the program runs the user is asked to put integer choice number to select the functionality of program like add, subtract etc. If the user enters a character or string an exception occurs and it is caught and the program moves on and the user can restart the program. But I want that when the user gives a bad input which causes the exception the program runs from same point i.e. Enter your choice no. to select functionality. And similar for further inputs in the program. Can anyone guide me?

```
package string;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class Calculator2 {

    double sum(double number1, double number2) {
        double operation = number1 + number2;
        return operation;
    }

    double subtract(double number1, double number2) {
        double operation = number1 - number2;
        return operation;
    }

    double multiply(double number1, double number2) {
        double operation = number1 * number2;
        return operation;
    }

    double divide(double number1, double number2) {
        double operation = number1 / number2;
        return operation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator2 f = new Calculator2();
        int choice;
        int z;

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Welcome To Sebiz Caculator:  Which Function Do You Want To Use");
                System.out.println("1.Addition");
                System.out.println("2.Subtraction");
                System.out.println("3.Multiplication");
                System.out.println("4.Division");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Please Enter Your Choice Number: ");
                choice = s1.nextInt();

                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
                double numb1 = s1.nextDouble();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
                double numb2 = s1.nextDouble();
                double result;
                String operation = "";

                switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    result = f.sum(numb1, numb2);
                    operation = "Sum";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = f.subtract(numb1, numb2);
                    operation = "Substraction";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = f.multiply(numb1, numb2);
                    operation = "Multiplication";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = f.divide(numb1, numb2);
                    operation = "Divison";
                    break;
                default:
                    result = 0;
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Please Enter a Valid Choice from 1 to 4");
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("The " + operation + " Of Two Numbers is: "
                        + result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out
                        .println("You Have Entered An Invalid Input. Please Enter 1 On Next Instruction To Start Again");
                s1.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Do You Want To perform Another Functionality?");
            System.out
                    .print("Press 1 to Continue and Press 2 to Terminate The Program ");
            z = s1.nextInt();
        } while (z == 1);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thank You For Using Sebiz Calculator");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code, it is really hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop wrapping a code that has a possibility to fail:

```
private double readDouble(Scanner scanner, String prompt) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        try {
            return scanner.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And then use that method to read `double` values:

```
double numb1 = readDouble(s1, "Please Enter the First Number: ");
```

Such a method would insistently repeat its prompt until a correct line is entered.

The same for reading `int` and whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works. I want to know how the while loop is working in this scenario? As 'while (true)' is used for infinite loop and we have to use 'break' to come out of the loop. How is code running again and again on entering bad input and how are we breaking out of the loop after entering the right output?

Comment: You can break out from a loop using `break`, `throw`, (or causing an exception in some other way), or using `return`. The latter is used in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much.. The thing that was confusing me was you didn't use break. Didn't know that return can also be used to break out of the loop..  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can win a lot by separating your operations. You can start with you scanner:

```
package string;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class Calculator2
{

    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    double getIntInput(String message) {
        try {
            System.out.print(message);
            return s1.nextInt();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("There was an error in your input it is not an int, please try again");
            return getIntInput(message);
        }
    }

    double getDoubleInput(String message) {
        try {
            return s1.nextDouble();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("There was an error in your input it is not a double, please try again");
            return getDoubleInput(message);
        }
    }

    double sum(double number1, double number2) {
        double operation = number1 + number2;
        return operation;
    }

    double subtract(double number1, double number2) {
        double operation = number1 - number2;
        return operation;
    }

    double multiply(double number1, double number2) {
        double operation = number1 * number2;
        return operation;
    }

    double divide(double number1, double number2) {
        double operation = number1 / number2;
        return operation;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calculator2 f = new Calculator2();
        int choice;
        int z;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Welcome To Sebiz Caculator:  Which Function Do You Want To Use");
                System.out.println("1.Addition");
                System.out.println("2.Subtraction");
                System.out.println("3.Multiplication");
                System.out.println("4.Division");
                System.out.println();
                choice = getIntInput("Please Enter Your Choice Number: ");

                System.out.println();
                double numb1 = getDoubleInput("Please Enter The First Number: ");
                System.out.println();
                double numb2 = getDoubleInput("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
                double result;
                String operation = "";

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        result = f.sum(numb1, numb2);
                        operation = "Sum";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        result = f.subtract(numb1, numb2);
                        operation = "Substraction";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        result = f.multiply(numb1, numb2);
                        operation = "Multiplication";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        result = f.divide(numb1, numb2);
                        operation = "Divison";
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = 0;
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("Please Enter a Valid Choice from 1 to 4");
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("The " + operation + " Of Two Numbers is: " + result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("You Have Entered An Invalid Input. Please Enter 1 On Next Instruction To Start Again");
                s1.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Do You Want To perform Another Functionality?");
            System.out.print("Press 1 to Continue and Press 2 to Terminate The Program ");
            z = s1.nextInt();
        }
        while (z == 1);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thank You For Using Sebiz Calculator");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its really useful and does the job. However i would like to  add something to it. In both the methods getIntInput and getDoubleInput when exception occurs we have to use nextLine() under catch just before returning the user input otherwise exception will occur again. Because when the user enters wrong input  it goes in the catch but the input is still there,so return getDoubleInput(message) throws another exception which is not catched and it crashes

Answer (score 2):

Put code which reads the number in a loop. Use `BufferReader` instead of `Scanner` like that: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))`. Then you can read an input with a `readLine()` method and check `choice` with `"string".contains` (or `matches`) for the wrong symbols. If so repeat the loop with `continue`, else parse it to an `int`. In the end of the loop simply use `break` for exit.

Comment: You can do `Scanner.nextLine()` too. | Are you suggesting to do `"a string" instanceof Number`, not sur to get that point ? | `String.contains(String)` seems complicated to check a complex content, `String.matches` would fit more.

Comment: yep, instanceof is a bad idea. corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method that read the values in the catch block.

Example

```
readValues(){
.
.
.
calc(num1,num2);
}

calc(int num1, int num2){
try{
   do 
   do
}catch(Exception e){
   readValues();
 }
}
```